# ¿como pasar dato obtenido de js a un input de html?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, formularios, entrada

Bien mi pregunta para algunos sera básica pero resulta que estoy haciendo un programa que incremente presionado un botón, todo bien hasta aquí, el problema es que

> quiero que ese incremento se imprima en un input de html ya que esto
>   lo estoy haciendo mediante alertas:

aquí el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>


    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form class="increment" action="index.html" method="post">

<input type="button" name="" value="contador" onclick="incremen()">

<input type="text" name="" value="" id="resultado">

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var contador=0;
function incremen() {


  contador++;
alert(contador);


}


    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplemente en lugar de hacer un `alert`,

1. puedes obtener el input a través de su `id` gracias al método `document.getElementById()`
2. posteriormente por medio de `value` le asignas el valor incrementado es decir el valor que esta almacenandose en la variable `contador`
3. Como le vas a asignar el valor generado a un input debes usar el método `value` para que cada vez que hagas clic se escriba dentro del **input**

**EJEMPLO**

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>


    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form class="increment" action="index.html" method="post">

<input type="button" name="" value="contador" onclick="incremen()">

<input type="text" name="" value="" id="resultado">

    </form>
<script>
      let contador = 0;
      function incremen(){
        contador++
        document.getElementById("resultado").value = contador
      }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```